How do I remove the red bubble on settings (macOS Sonoma)
Settings is always telling me to update, but I don't want to. I tried to fix it, but the notification just doesn't go away.


It cannot be removed. I would generally advise installing the latest version of Sonoma, at least; if you don't want to upgrade to Sequoia just yet.
